# Permutation Game - 2nd input case - explanation

Tags: algorithm

Permutation Game (30 Points)

Alice and Bob play the following game:

1) They choose a permutation of the first N numbers to begin with.

2) They play alternately and Alice plays first.

3) In a turn, they can remove any one remaining number from the permutation.

4) The game ends when the remaining numbers form an increasing sequence. The person who played the last turn (after which the sequence becomes increasing) wins the game.

Assuming both play optimally, who wins the game?

Input:
The first line contains the number of test cases T. T test cases follow. Each case contains an integer N on the first line, followed by a permutation of the integers 1..N on the second line.

Output:
Output T lines, one for each test case, containing "Alice" if Alice wins the game and "Bob" otherwise.

Constraints:
1 <= T <= 100
2 <= N <= 15

The permutation will not be an increasing sequence initially.

Sample Input:
2
3
1 3 2
5
5 3 2 1 4

Sample Output:
Alice
Bob

Explanation: For the first example, Alice can remove the 3 or the 2 to make the sequence increasing and wins the game.

Can someone please help me out on the second input case: 5 3 2 1 4

The increasing sequences possible are:
1) 3 4 - Removing 5 , 2 , 1 in any sequence
2) 2 4 - Removing 5 , 3 , 1 in any sequence
3) 1 4 - Removing 5 , 3 , 2 in any sequence

So the output should be Alice?

Please do not share any code. Thanks

Comment: You should probably define "optimally" in order to conclusively answer the question.  The correctness of @logic_max answer hinges upon the interpretation of that one word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Alice removes any of `5,3,2,1` then Bob removes `4`. So, the increasing sequence can be of only one element, elements can be removed in any order. Hence, Bob wins.

If Alice removes `4`, then also the increasing sequence has to be of one element. Bob wins.

So, Bob wins.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies my doubt

Comment: @user1301541 : May I know the link to the problem? Also, if this answer was helpful to you, don't forget to mark it as accepted :D

Comment: This is NOT correct.  The problem states that each player plays *optimally*.  In this case, the fewest steps to the solution is taken into account.  2 remaining elements is fewer steps than 1, so neither would remove the 4!

Comment: @JohnFisher : _Optimally_ here means that both players play to **win** the game.

Comment: @logic_max:  Without the information from the original poster, you can't know that for sure.

Comment: @JohnFisher, this is a typical game theory problem and this is how it is generally described. I agree that it is ambiguous and the problem that you thought is valid indeed.

Answer (score 0):

A possible case might be 4 or 5 is considered as increasing seq

As the input parameters are n>=2

But Alice would play optimally and remove 5 to win

Answer (score -1):

*NOTE:  This isn't a programming problem and really doesn't belong on this site...*

It sure looks like Alice should be the winner of the second test case.

Flow:

```
// Start state
5 3 2 1 4

// Alice remove 5
3 2 1 4

// Bob remove 3, 2, or 1
(2 1 4) or (3 1 4) or (3 2 4)

// Alice remove first number remaining
(1 4) or (2 4)

// Alice won!
```

Comment: Its related to coding but i am stuck at the second case after 4 hours

Comment: This is a programming problem based on game theory.

Comment: @logic_max: He merely wants the answer to the question, so it's a logic problem, not a programming problem.